# Noether Equation on Artin and Milgram Galois Theory book

Tags: galois-theory, noetherian

On Section K Chapter 2 of Galois Book by Artin and Milgram it discusses Noether Equation, but I'm not sure what Noether Equation this is, I know about Noether Equation for symmetry in physics but not sure about one in relation to Galois Theory.

The book states that $x_\sigma \cdot \sigma(x_\tau ) = x_{\sigma \tau}$ satisfies Noether Equation where $\sigma, \tau$ are automorphisms of field $E$ and $x_\sigma, x_\tau \in E$

If anyone knows what the Noether Equation they are referring to please elucidate :) Thanks in advance

Comment: That is the Noether equation they are talking about (it's a cocycle relation). Noether didn't just do one thing....

Comment: Yes sorry this is a cocycle condition (Galois cohomology) that is a function $f : G \to E^\times$ such that $f(\sigma\tau )/f(\sigma) = \sigma (f(\tau)/f(1))$ (which is a much weaker condition than $f(\sigma\tau )=\sigma(f(\tau ))$)